# Umbraco - Compilation Error

Tags: asp.net, server, umbraco

I have an issue with running my UMBRACO website live. I have uploaded it via FTP client to the server (using dailyrazor.com ASP.NET hosting) and it comes up with compliation error. Not sure why. I send my database too.

I can log into the backoffice and everything is fine in there but if I want to display a page is just keeps poping error for every page.

[Compilation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDPxu.png)

I would appreciate any help to be honest.

Thanks

Pav

Comment: Can you check if there is a web.config file located within the Views directory on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using Models Builder and the configuration is generating your models in file instead memory, so you have to include those cs files in your project so they are built along your site.

By default those classes are saved in /App_Data/Models but are hidden.

If you don't like this behaviour you can use PureLive as configuration but that will remove the benefits of using strongly typed models on your views.

[Models Builder configuration](https://github.com/zpqrtbnk/Zbu.ModelsBuilder/wiki/Install-And-Configure)

Comment: Hi Mario, yes that helped. It's all working now and as you mentioned above I prefer to use Dll instead of PureLive so I get the benefit of strongly typed models. Thank you

Comment: Done. Thanks for you help again.